# Select current tab in a Streamlit application

Tags: python, streamlit

In streamlit application, is there a way to get the current selected tab? Here is my use case - My UI has 3 tabs followed by a Submit button. For each tab selected in UI, I want to read specific UI widget values and then proceed with submit button action.
I tried to achieve this using session state variables but the change is these variables are not reflected in the button click handler function.
Below is my sample code.

```
import streamlit as st
import os
import json
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


def handle_submit():
    st.markdown("Submit clicked!" + str(st.session_state["selected_tab"]))


username = st.text_input("Username:", key="username3")
password = st.text_input("Password:", type="password", key="password3")

A, B, C = st.tabs(["A", "B", "C"])
with A:
    st.session_state["selected_tab"] = "A"
    run_type_prefix = st.text_input("Enter Run Name:", value="", key="key1")
    run_type_preference = st.text_input("Enter Run Preference:", value="", key="key2")
with B:
    st.session_state["selected_tab"] = "B"
    address = st.text_input("Enter Address:", value="", key="key3")
with C:
    st.session_state["selected_tab"] = "C"
    user_input = st.text_input("Enter your preference:", value="", key="key4")

col1, col2 = st.columns([1, 1])
with col1:
    submit = st.button("Submit", key="mock_submit", on_click=handle_submit)
with col2:
    cancel = st.button("Cancel", key="mock_cancel")
```

The st.session_state["selected_tab"] always returns tab "C". Is there any alternative to achieve this?

Comment: Have a look of what [tab](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/layout/st.tabs) is. Check the warning.

Comment: I know. I have used extre-streamlit-component for now but was mainly looking for any alternatives or workarounds to get this working with streamlit tabs.